# jQuery stops working on ASP.NET Wizard page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, wizard, wizard-control

I have a ASP.NET wizard that I need to use jQuery to manipulate some of the CSS styles.   For example if a certain criteria is met it will hide a button:

```
$("input[value='Continue']").css("display", "none")
```

This works great on the first page, but subsequent pages (loaded as controls .ascx) don't work.  The wizard doesn't load a new page each time, but simple reloads part of the content using the built in wizard feature.  Does anyone have any ideas how I can get jQuery to manipulate each page?  Sorry if this is a basic question, I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

When jQuery runs initially on page load, it binds to the page elements.  You can either use .live() or .delegate() to make it pick up the new items automatically, or you can put the jquery selectors/code in a function and run that on each control load to pick up the new elements.